# How to cycle on an iterator?

Tags: f#, iterator

In Rust, you can cycle on an iterator. For example:

```
fn main() {
    for i in (1..4).cycle().take(5) {
        print!("{} ", i);
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
1 2 3 1 2
```

How to do the same in F#?

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    seq { 1 .. 4 } |> (* Something *) |> Seq.take 5 |> Seq.iter (printf "%d ")
    0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in function, but you can easily create your own:

```
let cycle items = seq {
    while true do
        yield! items
}
```

or

```
let cycle' items =
    Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> items) |> Seq.concat
```

or

```
let rec cycle'' items = seq {
    yield! items
    yield! cycle'' items
}
```

Then

```
// 1 2 3 1 2
seq { 1 .. 3 } |> cycle |> Seq.take 5 |> Seq.iter (printf "%d ")
```

Comment: That's strange there is no builtin function. Maybe one could make a request for adding it in dotnet core. This function exists also in Haskell http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:cycle , it seems to be quite common.